# Column with two equations

Tags: amsmath, arrays

What is wrong with this column of two equations?

```
\begin{equation}
    \begin{align}
        u(x,t) &= \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}\\
        \mathbf{u}(\mathbf{r}, t) &= \left(\begin{array}
            \partial_y\phi(\mathbf{r},t)\\
            -\partial_x\phi(\mathbf{r},t)
        \end{array}\right).
    \end{align}
\end{equation}
```

[image: Output]

It drops `\partial` and output the error message "Package amsmath Error: Erroneous nesting of equation structures; LaTeX error: Illegal character in array arg."

Other ways to get the right output would also be welcome.

Comment: You're missing the required argument of the `array` environment. You should write `\begin{array}{c}`, not just `\begin{array}`. LaTeX is looking for the argument; the first thing it encounters is `\partial`, which gets gobbled, i.e., is not going to be typeset. And, because `\partial` is (unsurprisingly) not a valid column type for `array`, you get an error message about an illegal character...

Comment: A separate issue is that you mustn't encase an `align` enviroment inside an `equation` environment. You should either remove `\begin{equation}` and `\end{equation}` or replace `align` with `split`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is was answered in the comments

Answer (score 4):

Some suggestions and observations:

- The `array` environment takes a mandatory argument -- the column type(s) to be used. You haven't provided this argument, and LaTeX is therefore forced to (mis)interpret the next character it can find -- the `\partial` symbol -- as the argument of `array`, with disastrous consequences,

  I would actually like to suggest that you use a `pmatrix` environment instead of an `array` environment. That way, you can leave off the `\left(` and `\right)` directives, and the material is better, i.e., more tightly spaced too.
- You mustn't encase an `align` environment inside an `equation` environment. I suggest you replace `align` with `split`.
- Use a `\phantom{-}` directive in the first row of the column vector to get the correct (vertical) alignment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "split" and "pmatrix" environments
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        u(x,t) &= \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}\\
        \mathbf{u}(\mathbf{r}, t) &= 
        \begin{pmatrix}
            \phantom{-}\partial_y\phi(\mathbf{r},t)\\
                      -\partial_x\phi(\mathbf{r},t)
        \end{pmatrix}
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: with `pmatrix*[r]`, you don't need  `\phantom-}`.

Comment: @Bernard -- I guess you'd save 11 keystrokes ("\phantom{-}`" but add 8 more (two times "`*[r]`"), for a net saving of 3 keystrokes. I suppose one would begin to save more keystrokes if there were more `\phantom` statements... :-)

Comment: I don't mean quibbling, but it would  be only `5` keystrokes :o)

Answer (score 3):

The `array` environment expects a column-specifier (i.e. `l`,`c`,`r`) which gives the alignment of the columns.  That is the second error `LaTeX error: Illegal character in array arg`.  The first comes from the `align` environment being inside the `equation` environment, these both start display math and are incompatible, you can use either a single `align` environment or the `aligned` environment inside the `equation` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
        u(x,t) &= \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}\\
        \mathbf{u}(\mathbf{r}, t) &= \left(\begin{array}{r}
            \partial_y\phi(\mathbf{r},t)\\
            -\partial_x\phi(\mathbf{r},t)
        \end{array}\right).
    \end{align}
\hrule
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        u(x,t) &= \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}\\
        \mathbf{u}(\mathbf{r}, t) &= \left(\begin{array}{r}
            \partial_y\phi(\mathbf{r},t)\\
            -\partial_x\phi(\mathbf{r},t)
        \end{array}\right).
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Using the `pmatrix*[r]` environment would avoid having to set the `\left( … \right)` pair.

Comment: @Bernard using `pmatrix` does indeed make more sense, I probably should have paid more attention to what the OP actually wanted to be typeset! [Mico's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/342637/106162) covers use of the `pmatrix` environment so I think I'll leave my answer as is.

Comment: `array` is good, but it should be `\begin{array}{@{} r @{}}` in order to suppress the padding. Actually, I'd simply use `\begin{pmatrix}` without forcing right alignment.